# A conjecture on increasing, convex functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $F:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is twice-continuously-differentiable and satisfies $F(0)=0$, $F'\geq0$, and $F''\geq 0$.

Is it necessarily true that $$F''(x)x^2-F'(x)x+F(x)\geq0$$ for all $x\geq0$? Some tentative examples suggest that this is the case, but I’m not sure how to give a general proof, nor have I found a counterexample. [A hint or a reference would suffice, I’m not requesting a detailed answer.]

Thank you.

---

**Update:** Omran Kouba gave an excellent counterexample below. I’m still wondering whether the claim is true if one assumes, in addition, that $F'(0)=0$.

Comment: I'm not completely positive, but isn't $F''(x)x^2-F'(x)x+F(x)\geq -2 F'(x) x$ the best that you could say given what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter example is given by
$$f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1+e^x}{2}\right).$$
A counter example that satisfies also $f'(x)=0$ is given by
$$f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{1+e^x}{2}\right)-\frac{x}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the great counterexample. What if one insists also on $F'(0)=0$?

Comment: @triple_sec, It is done.